# Render Item left and right combination

Tags: css, react-native, tablet

I would like to render the item left and right in tablet. I have tried many ways. but nothing worked. Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue.

for example, array having some data. array = [firstname: 'aaaa',lastname: 'bbb', age: 15].
now i want to show the firstname in leftside, and lastname in rightside. then age will show the next line. if more data available, show left right combination.

```
Firstname           Lastname
aaa                 bbb

age                 Address
15                  cccc
```

````
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',}}>
    {data.map((item, index) => (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                <Text style={[commonStyles.darkBlack16,{ marginBottom: 8 }]}>{item.data</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    ))}
</View>
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this structure:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <View style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      <Text>Text</Text>
      <Text>Text</Text>
    </View>
  ))}
</View>
```